# Work-around to allow bit-shift of floating-point type in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

Let me start by saying that I understand that performing bit shifts and other bit-wise operations on a floating-point value sounds meaningless and ill-advised. So, moving beyond the "why would you do such a thing" responses...

I have a templated function that is handling some portion of serializing and deserializing various types to/from a binary stream. To "reassemble" multi-byte types from the byte stream, I am making use of bitshifts and bitwise ORs in the usual way. Please assume also that I have endianness and other such concerns under control.

Cutting to it, I'm looking for a clean way within a templated function to reliably cast a variable to an integer of the same size as the argument type (so that I'm allowed to perform bitwise operations on it); where that argument type might be a floating-point or any other arbitrary non-integer type. Pseudo-code example:

```
uint_same_size_as(U) sameSizeInt;
```

Where `uint_same_size_as(U)` would evaluate to, say, `uint32_t` when `U` is of type `float`, or `uint64_t` when `U` is of type `double`, etc.

Is there any such animal? And please forgive me if this is a basic feature of templates that I'm ignorant of.

Comment: Why do you need bit-shift at all? Work on byte level

Comment: To put it simply, I have reason to want to work on the bit level ... say I have a 32-bit type with more precision than I need but 24-bits is not enough ... I want the flexibility to serialize/deserialize a sequence of values of arbitrary bit-length.

Comment: Then use `unsigned char *` copy enough bytes and do shift on last byte if necessary (which I doubt would happen). And I doubt it will work correct for floating point data.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) even if you would realize the way that code would lead to UB. Better is to cast address of variable to `[unsigned] char *` and copy there in forward or reverse direction based on endianess. It is not clear why you need convoluted way with bit shifts to achive that.

Though you can use `std::bitset<sizeof<T>*CHAR_BIT>` in your template, but I strongly doubt that simply copying and shifting bits will work for floating types of different size.

Comment: Bit shifts are required because I am working with the bit as the smallest unit and not the byte.

So, if I have a 22-bit int, an 11-bit int, a 32-bit float, and a 7-bit int serialized into my binary stream without padding (e.g., byte alignment) in between then I'll obviously need bitshifts and bitmasks.

Comment: The only underlying types that will be of arbitrary length will be actual integers. I obviously won't be attempting to transmit or reconstruct a float or double of anything but 32-bit/64-bit.

The issue is that the 32-bits constituting a float may not end up byte-aligned in the stream.

Comment: @MatthewM. then implement packing/unpacking in `unsigned int` and do that in loop if underlying type is bigger. Bitwise operations should work fastest on int.

Comment: @Matthew M.: A useful old trick is to only bit-twiddle the odd-sized data, refilling a bit-buffer shift register from the stream whenever it runs dry and fetching raw bytes as-is for floats and other aligned data. Conversely the serializer reserves a spot for the bit-buffer at the emission of the first bit and then patches in the completed buffer farther back in the stream once full.